# Remove a view to show a previous view at a previous point on a scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm new to iOS and I have an initial view with a scrollview and a row of buttons.  When I press one it opens a new view with a new view controller, no problem.  What I'm having a problem with is when I try to return to the initial view the code I was using initializes a new instance of my initial view.  How can I return to my initial view at the same point on my scrollview that I pressed the button?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: didn't get you can you come again...

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController];
```

just use

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to dismiss the view.

Comment: haha thank you so much! for how hard I've been trying to figure that out it was so simple! Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble visualizing this. A little bit of the code in question would be helpful. Anyways are you using pushViewController:animated: and popViewControllerAnimated: to move back and forth between views?

to change views with button events

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

and to move back a view

```
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I got it figured out with the dismissmodalviewcontroller bit of code, but thank you so much for the support!

Answer (score 0):

For going to previous view always you should try to not alloc and just dismiss by calling

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

If u will do alloc every time you may face issue of memory and other things.....